# Max user connection error. When I uploaded my site online. but it works in localhost

Tags: php

This is my config.php code This works when I am on localhost but when I uploaded the site it does not work anymore. I tried searching here for answer but being a newbie makes my life hard.

```
<?php define("DB_HOST", "mysql.hostinger.ph"); 
define("DB_USER", "myuser");
define("DB_PASS", "mypassword");
define("DB_NAME", "mydbname");?>
```

And this is my Database.php code

```
    <?php 
$filepath = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
include_once($filepath.'/../config/config.php');
?>
<?php
Class Database{
 public $host   = DB_HOST;
 public $user   = DB_USER;
 public $pass   = DB_PASS;
 public $dbname = DB_NAME;


 public $link;
 public $error;

 public function __construct(){
  $this->connectDB();
 }

private function connectDB(){
 $this->link = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, 
  $this->dbname);
 if(!$this->link){
   $this->error ="Connection fail".$this->link->connect_error;
  return false;
 }
 }

// Select or Read data
public function select($query){
  $result = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);
  if($result->num_rows > 0){
    return $result;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
 }

// Insert data
public function insert($query){
 $insert_row = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);
 if($insert_row){
   return $insert_row;
 } else {
   return false;
  }
 }

// Update data
 public function update($query){
 $update_row = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);
 if($update_row){
  return $update_row;
 } else {
  return false;
  }
 }

// Delete data
 public function delete($query){
 $delete_row = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);
 if($delete_row){
   return $delete_row;
 } else {
   return false;
  }
 }

}
```

Then I get max user connection on Database.php line 22. I tried my best to search for a solution I hope that you can help my newbie mind ahhahah.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not in your code,possible in the mysql server.There are options in mysql config file,like this:

```
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
```

The problem maybe is the max_connections,which means this will allow 100 connections to the server at most.

If you are use third-party mysql server,this problem may happen...

Comment: Thanks for answering sir. Do you have any tips on how to fix this?

Comment: contact the mysql server provider

Comment: Thanks sir for tip I will try my best haha hopes this works.

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest reliable way is to contact your hosting provider. Most of the time, `max user connection errors` is solved this way.

Because usually you are not allowed (privileged) to execute useful queries to solve it(like `Grant usage...`) or change required configurations under a shared hosting environment.

But after all, it could be useful to read about it:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47131/how-to-get-rid-of-maximum-user-connections-error
- [proper way to solve mysql max user connection error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573338/proper-way-to-solve-mysql-max-user-connection-error)
- [How to solve MySQL max_user_connections error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183727/how-to-solve-mysql-max-user-connections-error)

Comment: @Galvezo.A Hope it helps